# Why is Eclipse deleting my files and putting them in 'Local History'!

Tags: html, eclipse, templates, flexbuilder

Several times now I've had Eclipse delete files for me seemingly randomly - then they appear under the 'Local History' option.

What is going on! I'm definitely not just deleting things by mistake.

Most recently it deleted my template files under `html-template` which are quite important!

I have an AIR project and a web project that references the `src` directory inside the AIR project. Usually I close one project while working on the other.

FYI: Currently my backup solution is `Windows Home Server` which means I have to go home to find a file if its lost in some other fashion and not in history. Yes I do plan to rectify that!

Comment: can you give an example to reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

Under Local History you can find the previous versions of your files, after you modified it.

Didn't you set this folder as the output folder for compiling? Then eclipse could clear the files during build.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is an external application that is deleting or moving your files. Eclipse's local history simply keeps of copy of your files for quick reverting later.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying using a different IDE for a while like NetBeans, and see if the files are still being deleted. Eclipse probably isn't the suspect, as those files would be in local history even if they were not deleted.

I am trying to fix an issue like this myself, I find that when I look into files that have been deleted with another text editor like GEdit, they look like they have been corrupted. I hadn't previously noticed that eclipse kept them in local history, thank you for that. I had been using gitHub for backups before and restoring from that.

If I find that switching to another IDE fixes it, or any other info, I will update this post.